# Converting Invalid DateTime

Tags: c#, timezone

I need to Convert DateTime from UTC to local time, For that I had Validated the date time before converting to local time using TimeZoneInfo IsInValidTime method.

I'm getting Invalid date time for a particular date time, How to convert this date to a valid one?

Here is the Sample code:

```
_timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
var dateTime = "10/03/2013 2:12:00 AM";
DateTime universalFormatDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime).GetUniversalFormatDateTime();
if (_timeZoneInfo.IsInvalidTime(universalFormatDateTime)) Console.Write("Invalid DateTime\n");
```

Comment: What is the resulting value of `DateTime`? What culture is being used for the conversion (the date is ambiguous - it can be March 10th or October 3rd, depending on culture).

Comment: It's really unclear what result you *want*. If the given local date/time is invalid due to being skipped, what do you want to happen? (Note that Noda Time makes it easier to say what you want to happen ;)

Comment: @Arshad: No, that's converting UTC to local, which doesn't have the same problems around daylight saving transitions.

Comment: `GetUniversalFormatDateTime` is not a method of `DateTime` instance. How you compiled the code above?

Comment: GetUniversalFormatDateTime is my method `public static class DateTimeExtensions
    {
        public static DateTime GetUniversalFormatDateTime(this DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day,
                        dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute, dateTime.Second, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        }
    } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What framework are you using?

Isn't ToUniversalTime() the correct choice?

```
DateTime universalFormatDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime).ToUniversalTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the DateTimeKind of your Date time. Add this before perform the validation:

```
universalFormatDateTime = DateTime
   .SpecifyKind(universalFormatDateTime,DateTimeKind.Local);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
_timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
var dateTime = "10/03/2013 2:12:00 AM";
DateTime universalFormatDateTime = Convert
                                  .ToDateTime(dateTime, new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
                                  .ToUniversalTime();
if (_timeZoneInfo.IsInvalidTime(universalFormatDateTime))
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid DateTime");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Valid DateTime");
```

You can look at the [Convert.ToDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t.aspx) articke for future reference.